# Uso de "codoñate" fuera de las regiones catalano-parlantes

Tags: uso-de-palabras, sustantivos, comida

Hoy he descubierto que a la carne de membrillo también se la conoce por el nombre de *codoñate*:

> **[codoñate](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9dtxCE9)**
>
> ```
> Del cat. codonyat.
> ```
>
> 1. m. Dulce de membrillo.

Yo esta palabra no la había oído en la vida. Al parecer lleva en el diccionario más de un siglo y medio, y no está exenta de polémica. Por un lado apenas hay 3 casos de *codoñate/codonate* en el CORDE. El primero es del *Libro del buen amor*, del siglo XIV (como *codonate*). Una ficha del *Fichero general* de la RAE dice:

> Covarrubias [...] dice que en Valencia llaman "a la carne de membrillo o conserva *codoñate*". Si la Academia no dispone de más documentación, parece excesivo dar en el Dicc. como general una castellanización del cat. *codonyat* que no debe de haber penetrado en el área del castellano.
>   El primer inconveniente es hacer dudar de la forma *codonate* de los códices 5 y 6 del *Libro del buen amor*, 1334 [...]. Corominas ya dice que en este pasaje "deberá leerse seguramente *codoñate*. Y, sin embargo, *codonate* parece legítimo.
>   En zonas castellanas fronterizas, la *-ny* final del cat. *codony* 'membrillo' se sustituyó en muchos casos por *-n*: y ya por influencia de *codón* se dijo *codonero* y *codonate*.

Al margen del debate de si debería ser *codoñate* o *codonate*, ninguna de las dos formas la había oído antes. El caso es que el diccionario la marca como de uso general, sin determinar región de uso como hemos visto en otros casos. Así pues, pregunto: ¿es la voz *codoñate* conocida y usada en áreas que no sean de influencia del catalán?

Comment: Aquí uno en zona catalano-parlante que nunca la había oído en castellano : )

Comment: @fedorqui pero imagino que sí usáis _codonyat_ para la carne de membrillo, ¿no?

Comment: Sí sí, absolutamente. Lo que nunca oí es su versión castellana _codoñate_ (comentando la parte final de _¿es la voz *codoñate* conocida y usada en áreas que no sean de influencia del catalán?_)

Comment: @fedorqui debe de ser pues una castellanización muy poco usada y conocida, aunque precisamente acabo de encontrar una [receta de "codoñate"](https://sevilla.abc.es/gurme/recetas/codonate/) en el ABC de Sevilla que tiene muy buena pinta. :)

Comment: Codoñate = placer azucarado :) Si algún día puedes, prueba los _pastissets_ mallorquines o _crespells_ menorquines (es lo mismo).

Comment: Yo (Colombia) no conocía ni codoñate ni membrillo :-)

Comment: En italiano los membrillos se llaman `mele cotogne` o sea manzanas de Cydonia (antigua ciudad en Creta). En catalán se llaman `codonys` por la misma razón. El nombre latin de los membrillos es `Cydonia oblonga`. Probablemente el nombre español de "codoña" se habrá perdido como muchas otras palabras.

Comment: Véase [*dulce de membrillo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulce_de_membrillo) de Wikipedia en español; también [*marmelada*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marmelada) de Wikipedia en portugués.

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que se utiliza aún, viene del castellano antiguo y en zonas de montaña de León, Asturias, Cantabria se utiliza más que el 'DULCE DE MEMBRILLO 'que todos conocemos.

Answer (score 0):

En Asturias fue usado en el pasado, pero a mí ya no me ha tocado oírlo en boca de nadie. Está prácticamente en desuso.

En cualquier caso, veamos las referencias en los diccionarios:

- Primera aparición en un diccionario: 1846, *Nuevo diccionario de la lengua castellana* (Vicente Salvá).
- Primera aparición en la RAE: 1925, *Diccionario de la lengua española*.